# Was the first child of Dovid and Batsheva supposed to be Moshiach?

Tags: messiah, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, baby-infant

Rav Neventzal’s sichos Bereishis sichah 36, explains that Dovid knew via ru’ach ha’kodesh that Moshiach was going to come from his relationship with Batsheva. I heard that this refers to the child who subsequently died. Is there a source for the idea that the child of Dovid and Batsheva was supposed to be Moshiach?

Comment: Heard the same thing from the Russian lectures of one of my *rabbeim* who sourced his rebbi, R' Moshe Frank. Not sure of the real textual source in the *meforshim*, looking fwd to find out.

Comment: http://haravginsburgh.com/2014/06/13/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2/